# How to pass hundreds of lines of js code to Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm really tired of the stupid library selenium.
If you want to pass js code to Selenium, use:

```
`js = "JS code here"
driver.excute_script(js)`
```

However, my js code has multiple lines, which looks like below:

```
setTimeout(function(){
l = document.getElementsByClassName("test-option");
    for(const a in l){if(l[a]==undefined || l[a]==null)
        continue

    if(l[a].innerText !=undefined && l[a].innerText.includes("Miracle"))
    {
        l[a].click();
    }
}
}, 2000);
```

When you delete the new line char in each line and put them together with
single or double quotes. Selenim starts to spark. Is there any better way
to pass the js string? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Aside from being messy that shouldn't be a problem:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  setTimeout(function(){
    l = document.getElementsByClassName("test-option");
      for(const a in l){if(l[a]==undefined || l[a]==null)
        continue

      if(l[a].innerText !=undefined && l[a].innerText.includes("Miracle"))
      {
        l[a].click();
      }
    }
  }, 2000)
""")
```